# Command substitution in zsh

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

I'm trying to use simple command substitution in zsh to `cd` to the output of another command (`which` with `dirname`).

- `which git` → `/usr/bin/git` as expected;
- `dirname $(which git)` → `/usr/bin` as expected;
- `cd $(dirname $(which git))` →`cd: no such file or directory: ^[[0m^[[0m/usr/bin`

What's happening here? What is `^[[0m` and why is it showing up all of a sudden?

Comment: `cd $(dirname $(which git))` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing this line in `~/.zshrc` fixed it:

`trap 'printf "\e[0m" "$_"' DEBUG`